# What gamekit/engine should I use for 2d simple game in ios?

Tags: ios7, game-engine, gamekit, 2d-games

I'm thinking in doing my first ios game, I am new in ios programming and I need your advice.
The game will be very simple and 2d, imagine something like a card games.
My doubt is if i should use UIKit, spritekit, cocos2d... What is the recommended for 2d simple games with few animations?
Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend cocos2d, since it is widely used by many developers and can also be used for serious game development, so when you feel that you've picked it up and gotten familiar with the api, it will be something that you can continue using after the first one is released.
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/games/
As you can see, many successful games and it has a nice collection of features build it, so that is always handy even tho' in your first title and development training program you would also like to get as close as possible to basics which is the best way of learning, it will also allow you this.
I would not even consider UIKit as THE platform to approach at all.
as for spritekit, that could go ether way, i wouldnt use it, but it is not useless if you know what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, i would really suggest you CORONA SDK. Specially for simple and 2D game development. It's very fast and easy to understand and you can create game faster then cocos2d and objective-c development. Also it's support cross platform.

http://coronalabs.com/

With Corona, you will develop mobile apps in record time.

Comment: But Corona it's paid... I prefer free alternatives :S

Comment: No, its free and it's called Starter version for it. I used starter. Even they allow apple store publishing by using Starter version. you just have to go for paid for some special features.